# Reading from file into Python data structure

Tags: python

I have a file which has the following format:

```
[
["unique_id1", {"cc":15, "dd":30}], ["unique_id2", {"cc": 184,"dd":10}], ...
]
```

I want to directly read the file and put data in a Python data structure. For now, I'm processing using regular expressions.  Is there a command that I'm missing  to read it directly?

Comment: That looks like json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file format is probably JSON from what you've shown us.

You can parse it by doing

```
import json
out = json.load(file_object)
```

Either that or its a literal

```
out = eval(file_object.read())
```

OR (Preferred)

```
import ast
out = ast.literal_eval(file_object.read())
```

Comment: json format is okay, if you could write how can I loop through efficiently, I will appreciate that.

Comment: You don't have to use a for loop for JSON, you just read it in and it just works.

Comment: I understand, but I need to access some uniqueids and process them.

Comment: then use a normal for loop to iterate through the list created and access the uid with value[0]

Comment: not sure why this got no votes, you should parse json with the json lib

Comment: it did get an upvote. it then got a downvote (anyone tell me why so I can improve it?)

Comment: I upvoted, I would not worry about the dv, some people  dv whether the answer is correct or not.

Comment: your answer json solved my problem, thanks. Accepted.

Comment: @muddyfish Upvoted you just to compensate the stupid downvote!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)

```
import ast
f = open('myfile.txt')
print ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), it turns strings that contain Python objects, into Python objects:

```
>>> import ast
>>> l = ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3]')
>>> type(l)
<class 'list'>
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```

So you would read the data from your file and turn it into a list:

```
with open('file.txt') as infile:
    data = ast.literal_eval(infile.read())
```

Comment: I guess the problem is after reading the file, processing them. Thanks, this helped.